# Godot save select screen

Tags: save, godot, gdscript

What would be the best way to create a save select screen with more than 1 selectable save file, so far i have managed to get one save file working but i don't know how i would manage more than one of them, saving to it and loading that particular one when needed

here's the code for my saving and loading system

```
const FILE_NAME = "user://game-data1.json"

var player = {
    "collected_level_one":false,
    
}

func save():
    var file = File.new()
    file.open(FILE_NAME, File.WRITE)
    file.store_string(to_json(player))
    file.close()

func load():
    var file = File.new()
    if file.file_exists(FILE_NAME):
        file.open(FILE_NAME, File.READ)
        var data = parse_json(file.get_as_text())
        file.close()
        if typeof(data) == TYPE_DICTIONARY:
            player = data
        else:
            printerr("Corrupted data!")
    else:
        printerr("No saved data!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple save files. You would need use multiple selectable slots and a save and load button. That get your selected item and then either save or load, when they are clicked.

**Calling save or load:**

```
# Clicked save button.
func _on_Button_pressed_save() -> void:
    # Get the selected save/load slot.
    var index
    # Save into the selected file.
    SaveSystem.save(index)

# Clicked load button.
func _on_Button_pressed_save() -> void:
    # Get the selected save/load slot.
    var index
    # Load the selected file.
    SaveSystem.load(index)
```

You would also need to add your Savesystem script as a [`Singleton (Autoload)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html). So that you can access it easily in other scripts.

---

After you've added the call to the functions you need to change them accordingly to be able to manage multiple save files.

**Managing multiple save files:**

```
# Clicked save button.
const FILE_NAME = "user://game-data"
const FILE_EXTENSION = ".json"

var player = {
    "collected_level_one":false,
}

# Saves into the file with the given index.
func save(index : int) -> void:
    var file := File.new()
    var file_name := FILE_NAME + to_str(index) + FILE_EXTENSION
    file.open(file_name, File.WRITE)
    file.store_string(to_json(player))
    file.close()

# Loads the file with the given index.
func load(index : int) -> void:
    var file := File.new()
    var file_name := FILE_NAME + to_str(index) + FILE_EXTENSION
    if file.file_exists(file_name):
        file.open(FILE_NAME, File.READ)
        var data := parse_json(file.get_as_text())
        file.close()
        if typeof(data) == TYPE_DICTIONARY:
            player = data
        else:
            printerr("Corrupted data!")
    else:
        printerr("No saved data!")
```